# How can I allow core, plugin, theme update checks only for selected admins?

Tags: wp-admin, updates

[How to disable core and plugin updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120589/how-to-disable-core-and-plugin-updates) talks about generally disabling everything.

I'd like to keep update checks going for a select few admin accounts only. What's the best method? You can't check for user name at `wp-config.php` phase, right?

EDIT I mean disabling the whole update check process, not only the notifications. With a production site where you might have 15 HTTP requests going out for an update check run, it will cause significant delays in admin for people who this operation is not at all relevant for.

Comment: +1 but I do not think you are asking the right question. You are probably more interested in the notifications not displaying, and/or some admins not being able to update

Comment: WordPress checks for updates for itself, it doesn't really make sense to say that update _checks_ should be disabled per-user. Do you mean notifications, or the ability to update?

Comment: It does make sense to say "update checks should be enabled per-user". Admin page load speed is of great importance on our platform, since multiple people work on content and content configuration, but have no business updating anything.

Update checks to a large number of plugins, when it triggers, significantly slows perceived admin page load speed. Plugin set is already linted and only business critical things are in action.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should better create a custom role for "administrators-non-administrators" without the update_core, update_plugins and update_themes capabilities.

Comment: I like this idea and am going to give it a shot. Members plugin should allow also assigning multiple roles to everybody relevant.

Comment: it seems like these capabilities only control the visibility of menu items. Update checks do not check for these caps.