# Can plugin automatically update if i hide the update notification?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I'm trying to remove the plugin update functionality from specific plugins. I have searched about it and find a good [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/disable-update-notification-for-individual-plugins?answertab=active#tab-top). According to the answer below function actually hiding the update notification from plugins and its working fine.

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['akismet/akismet.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

But I wanted to know can plugin automatically update or not? If not then i think above function will be enough for prevent the plugin update. Can any one please guide me about this I will appreciate. Thank You.

Comment: AFAIK, plugins can't auto-update. I'm just wondering why you would want to disable updates, updates are quite important

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks for guideline. I'm removing  updates due to the security purpose (Hacking). So should i remove the update or not? Can you kindly clear my concept. Thank you

Comment: I cannot see how stopping updates will stop a site from being hacked. Updates are usually there to fix security issues in previous versions. Simply stopping those updates can actually lead to a bigger change of actually being hacked. If your host is running outdated PHP versions, or you are running outdated plugins, themes or WordPress, or you have bad code somewhere in a theme or plugin, you will most probably get hacked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a definition of what is "auto update", but in the most general sense, a plugin can do whatever any other part of wordpress can do therefor a plugin can trigger an auto update without human intervention.

On the more practical side, this is very unlikely, and hiding the indication should be good enough for all practical usage. Still hiding information is usually something that will come to bite you back in one way or another when it is not your own site. It is just not your site and you should not prevent users from having full control of their site.

If you have a contract in which you are the only one responsible of adminning the site then the proper thing to do is just not to let any one else have the capabilities you do not wish them to have, or just have no one else in admin role (not sure how that works with comment moderation, therefor the capabilities path might be the only way to go).