# How to disable admin notice in child theme?

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme, notices

*Similar to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/206735/92434, [Disable update notification for individual plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20580/92434).*

I have purchased a theme, which displays a notice in admin panel to all administrators to install recommended plugins.

In child theme, how can I disable this notice to make it not appear any more in the admin panel in the future?

Parent theme is using [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) to display the notice.

Comment: that will depend on the theme. without knowing how the theme displays the notice it will be hard to answer.

Comment: isn't there a standard way to do it?

Comment: kinda there is, but you don't know if the theme follows it, and you need some specific details for that. Try to search for `admin_notice` hook at the source code of the theme

Comment: looked into code and got to know parent theme is using TGM Plugin Activation http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: ok, at this I just can't help anymore as I don't know how TGM works

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you don't need those plugins and if TGM is not tied up with any required licenses for your plugins, just [pull TGM Plugin Activation right out](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/faq/#uninstalling-tgmpa).

It's a three step process. One: find and delete the plugin registration function.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Required and Recommended Plugins
 */
function prefix_register_plugins() {

    /**
     * Array of plugin arrays. Required keys are name and slug.
     * If the source is NOT from the .org repo, then source is also required.
     */
    $plugins = array(

        // WordPress SEO
        array(
            'name'     => 'WordPress SEO by Yoast',
            'slug'     => 'wordpress-seo',
            'required' => false,
        ),
        ...
    );

    tgmpa( $plugins );
}
add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'prefix_register_plugins' );
```

Two: find and delete the require_once() call that references the TGMPA class file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Include the TGM_Plugin_Activation class.
 */
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
```

Three: remove `class-tgm-plugin-activation.php` as it's not needed any more.

Comment: Consider I want to disable notices in the child theme only, not changing original theme, eg. because of its updates.

Comment: These notices will get passed through to the child theme as long as it's a child of its parent. I.e. this part of the code will be run as long as the child and parent are connected. In the best case, you'd still have to modify the parent them not to run the plugin activation when called on by a child theme. If there's a better answer, I'd love to hear it too.

Comment: This shouldnt be a correct answer because when the parent theme is updated any changes will be lost.

Comment: Rhys, there's two simple solutions here. 1. don't update the parent theme (unless for security fixes, see 2). 2. follow the same steps on update. It's also possible that the TGM section will be in unchanged files so you could just re-add the edited files).

Comment: I think this is a good question and not off topic. The same WP thought control police which don't want you to be able to disable theme notifications or license notifications seem to be downvoting my answer. A better answer would be more useful.